# ERROR: syntax error at or near "." - JPA Pageable

Tags: spring, jpa, pageable

`repository`:

```
@Repository
public interface PostRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Post, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT p.postComments FROM Post p WHERE p.webId = ?1")
    Page<PostComment> findCommentsByWebId(String webid, Pageable pageable);

}
```

`Post` entity:

```
public class Post {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "web_id")
    private String webId;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "title")
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "description")
    private String description;

    @Column(nullable = false, name = "mature")
    private boolean mature;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "post")
    private Cover cover;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<PostView> postViews;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tag",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id"))
    private List<Tag> tags;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<PostDownvote> postDownvotes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<PostUpvote> postUpvotes;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "post")
    private List<PostComment> postComments;

    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private Timestamp createdAt;

    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private Timestamp updatedAt;
}
```

**The problem**: When returning plain `List<PostComment>` from the query method everything works fine. But if I change it to `Page<PostComment>` (I need total elements count), I get the following error:

```
2022-08-03 22:29:41.399 ERROR 9192 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 14
Hibernate: select tags0_.post_id as post_id1_6_0_, tags0_.tag_id as tag_id2_6_0_, tag1_.id as id1_10_1_, tag1_.name as name2_10_1_ from post_tag tags0_ inner join tag tag1_ on tags0_.tag_id=tag1_.id where tags0_.post_id=?
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
```

It is very difficult to debug this. Does anyone have any clue on what is wrong?

I need BOTH paging and total amount of elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you are not able to fetch the part of the inner collection. But you could reach it from the another side of the bi-directional relationship

```
@Repository
public interface PostCommentRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<PostComment, Long> {

     @Query(value = "SELECT pc FROM PostComment pc WHERE pc.post.webId = ?1")
     Page<PostComment> findCommentsByWebId(String webid, Pageable pageable);

     // or better using Spring Data naming conventions just
     Page<PostComment> findAllByPostWebId(String webid, Pageable pageable);
}
```

Comment: How come if I return plain List (instead of Page instance) from the method in PostRepository it works fine? I get the List<PostComment> as a return value normally.

Comment: I could only rephrase what I have already written. Having 1-to-many relationship you could fetch only the entire inner collection (well, you could filter it on java side later but it is another story). There are some basic tricks with @LazyCollection Hibernate-specific feature, but you can't still get the comments by the certain predicate. But the bidirectional relationship allows you to do whatever you want from the another (postComments) side.

Comment: So you are telling me that in 1-to-many relationship JPA can't fetch {size} elements from inner collection by a {offset}? It only can fetch the entire collection? That doesn't make sense. If it can fetch the entire collection, it also can page-fetch.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need a total count you should avoid querying list of entities which could be very memory intensive.

So in your **PostCommentRepository** try the following:

```
long countAllByPost_WebId(String webId);
```

Comment: I need both paging and total amount of elements. Edited the post.